# How to Identify Inactive/Unused Sites within SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online

I am searching for a definitive solution to accurately identify which sites (and the data contained in those sites) within my SharePoint Online tenant have not been accessed on interacted with by any user for x amount of time, and then generate an Excel report with a list of those sites.

I have been trying to find the solution to this problem for several months to no avail. I see that this question or similar has been asked here before but I do not believe that the correct solution was identified, at least for my circumstances.

Thus far, I have tried developing scripts to access the LastItemUserModifiedDate property for all sites with both the SharePoint Online Management Shell, and the PnP management shell. No matter what I do, I either get incorrect results or errors.

I have tried using all the methods described in the SharePoint Dictionary blog, and I have tried using the browser centre, which I have found to display inaccurate results. Either I get a result which is skewed by automated system actions, or SharePoint is reporting an actively used site as completely unused.

We have Multifactor Authentication enabled across O365 and I have found in some instances this seems to cause issues with certain scripts, even though I modify them to use the interactive web login.

Can anyone provide me with some advice about how I should approach this please? Any anecdotes on how you manage unused sites within your own setup would also be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

**PnP PowerShell to Get Unused Site Collections in the past 30 days**

```
$TenantAdminURL = "https://Crescent-Admin.SharePoint.com"
$TenantURL = "https://Crescent.SharePoint.com"
$DaysInActive = 30 # number of days to check since last modified
$CSVPath = "C:\Temp\InactiveSites.csv"
 
#Connect to Admin Center
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $TenantAdminURL -Credentials $Cred
     
#Get All Site collections - Exclude BOT, Video Portals and MySites
$SiteCollections = Get-PnPTenantSite -Filter "Url -like $TenantURL -and Url -notlike '-my.sharepoint.com/' -and Url -notlike '/portals/'"
 
#Calculate the Date
$Date = (Get-Date).AddDays(-$DaysInActive).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
 
#Get All Site collections where the content modified
$InActiveSites = $SiteCollections | Where {$_.LastContentModifiedDate -le $Date} | Select Title, Url, LastContentModifiedDate, Template, StorageMaximumLevel
 
#Export to CSV
$InActiveSites
$InActiveSites | Export-Csv -Path $CSVPath -NoTypeInformation
```

[image]

[image]

More information, please view the below post.

- **[SharePoint Online: Find All Unused Sites based on Last Modified
  Date](https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/08/sharepoint-online-find-unused-sites-using-powershell.html)**

Comment: I have tried this script, unfortunately the results returned are inaccurate due to automated system actions causing false positives. the LastItemModifiedDate returns a timestamp of reflecting changes made by the system, where as I want to know if any user has accessed the site or files within it.

Comment: EDIT: I have changed lastItemModifiedDate to LastItemUserModifiedDate and I am getting better results although the date function doesn't work as I am getting results from all sites whether I input 1 day or 1000 days

Comment: Hi, Bosco. Thanks for your reply. I'm glad to hear that your problem has been solved. Have a nice day！

Answer (score 0):

In the article above author use LastContentModifiedDate Site property, but actually there are also

- LastItemModifiedDate Web property
- LastItemUserModifiedDate Web property
- LastModifiedDateTime MS Graph site property

[Here are the differences](https://vladilen.com/sharepoint/spo-site-lastcontentmodifieddate-vs-lastitemmodifieddate-vs-lastitemusermodifieddate/)